# Assembly dollar sign minus number

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-16, tasm

Suppose I have the following code (it delivers an error: `Expected scalar type`):

```
a db 10 dup(2)
b db $-3
```

Is there any way to do something equivalent to that in assembly?
EDIT: I'm using TASM for 8086

Comment: What assembler you are using? And what processor you are targeting?

Comment: Is it perhaps because `$` is a `word` or `dword` value, and you're trying to stuff it into a `byte`?

Answer (score 0):

Which assembler? `dup` looks like Masmese. In Nasm, `b db ($-$$) - 3` will do it. Seems improbable that you want to put this value in a byte. I'd go with `dd` or in 64-bit code `dq`.

I don't think you'll find the word "scalar" anywhere in the Nasm Manual, but it means "not a relocatable value". `$`, like any label, is relocatable, but the difference between two labels is a "scalar" value.

Unlike C, we don't have an "assembly language standards committee". Assembler authors are free to use any syntax they like - and they do! In AT&T syntax (which this is not) `$` has a completely different meaning. May not work in Masm, but worth a try. You really need to specify which assembler!

Comment: I'm using turbo assembler for 8086 @FrankKotler

Comment: If what I showed doesn't work for Tasm, try putting a label wherever you intend `$` to start counting. You've indicated that that works. I know Nasm, mostly...

Answer (score 0):

It is not a scalar type, because a **db** variable holds **one** byte and ($-3) means the current offset minus 3 (the offset is a word (**2** Bytes) in 16-bit mode or a double word (**4** Bytes) in 32-bit mode)